# TFS Template Customization - SharePointPortal site

Tags: sharepoint, process, tfs

I am customizing a Process Template for TFS2008.

I am using the "MSF for Agile... v4.2" template as the base template and would like to set the version control settings of the "Project Management" document library todo the following:

- Major Versions : Enabled
- Documents must be checked our before they can be edited

I'm using the editor GUI provided by the tfs powertools, however it does not appear these settings are available.

Is it possible to define these settings in the WssTasks.XML file or do I need to approach this from a different angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation I think the way to achieve this is by creating a custom document library definition in sharepoint and modify the process template to create a document library using the custom definition. something like this :-

http://vspug.com/tbaginski/2007/08/16/creating-a-custom-document-library-feature-in-wss-v3-moss-2007/